# Using OPENXML for extracting data

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-openxml

i have xml text, and want extract data

```
DECLARE @d_txt  VARCHAR(max)
SET @d_txt = '
<DI_List>
  <SDI>
    <a>6559864</a>
    <DI>
      <Id>3036780478</Id>
      <mic>
        <date>2022-11-13</date>
        <kod>774673</kod>
      </mic>
      <mic>
        <date>2022-11-11</date>
        <kod>774673</kod>
      </mic>  
    </DI>
  </SDI>
</DI_List>'

DECLARE @d_xml  INT

exec sp_xml_preparedocument @d_xml output, @d_txt;

        SELECT *
        FROM OPENXML(@d_xml, '/DI_List/SDI', 0) WITH
        (
            Id  VARCHAR(30) 'DI/Id',
            nmic XML 'DI/mic'
        )

EXEC sys.sp_xml_removedocument @d_xml
```

i got

| Id | nmic |
| --- | --- |
| 3036780478 | `<mic><date>2022-11-13</date><kod>774673</kod></mic>` |

but i want nmic field contains both  nodes, not first only

| Id | nmic |
| --- | --- |
| 3036780478 | `<mic><date>2022-11-13</date><kod>774673</kod></mic><mic><date>2022-11-11</date><kod>774673</kod></mic>` |

can i doit with SQL Server OPENXML?

Comment: Why do you want to use `OPENXML`? Why not use XQuery? What are you actual expected results here?

Comment: i want 2 xml nodes in nmic field,       <mic>
        <date>2022-11-13</date>
        <kod>774673</kod>
      </mic>
      <mic>
        <date>2022-11-11</date>
        <kod>774673</kod>
      </mic>

Comment: [Edit] your question with your expected results,

Comment: Your expected result isn't well formed, as you'd need a root node to hold the two sibling nodes you want to extract - I think this is why you can't get the result you want specifically as XML. You can still get the result you want with a bit of `XQuery` though, use `nmic.query('DI/mic')` - [example on db<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/uqimvFAZ)

Comment: `OPENXML()`, and its companions `sp_xml_preparedocument/sp_xml_removedocument` is a proprietary Microsoft API. It is currently kept just for backward 
compatibility with the obsolete SQL Server 2000. Starting from SQL Server 2005 onwards it supports w3c's XQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, use XQuery instead of `OPENXML`; `OPENXML` is a far older and "clunky" way of querying XML. Also, your XML is in the wrong datatype, there is an `xml` data type for XML.

If you switch to XQuery, and change the data type, this is much easier:

```sql
DECLARE @d_txt  xml --varchar is the wrong datatype
SET @d_txt = '
<DI_List>
  <SDI>
    <a>6559864</a>
    <DI>
      <Id>3036780478</Id>
      <mic>
        <date>2022-11-13</date>
        <kod>774673</kod>
      </mic>
      <mic>
        <date>2022-11-11</date>
        <kod>774673</kod>
      </mic>  
    </DI>
  </SDI>
</DI_List>';


SELECT SDI.DI.value('(Id/text())[1]', 'bigint') AS Id,
       SDI.DI.query('mic') AS nmic
FROM @d_txt.nodes('DI_List/SDI/DI')SDI(DI);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/B38RGads)

Comment: Lurnu, thank you for advice. Its old legacy project and i don't want to rewrite all sql from OPENXML to XQuery. But in future projects i can try to use xquery, thank you again :)